# How not to run Pi specific code in other machines (x86_64 Linux)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, wiringpi

While coding a Raspberry Pi application I do use my PC most of the time since it is a little faster then the Pi.

Today I got the following message when a [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) specific code (`wiringPiSetup();`) got called:

```
piBoardRev: Unable to determine board revision from /proc/cpuinfo
 -> No hardware line
 ->  You may want to check:
 ->  http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=184410#p184410
```

I would like to skip Raspberry Pi specific code (such this WiringPi part) but execute the rest when running on a PC.

Actually how should I approach this issue?

Comment: At this point, you're the only one who's seen your code, so you're the only one who can know what parts to cut. In general, you'll need to *mock* the parts that you can't run on your PC.

Comment: Should I run Pi specific code in run time like a plugin?

Comment: No, just write your own replacement library that mocks the functionality of the library you're replacing.

Comment: I never touched the mocking area. Would you mind to give an introductory suggestion about which tools to use (portability across Linux/Windows is appreciated)?

Answer (score 1):

My first solution would be to so include the pi specific code in something like

```
#ifdef __arm__
  /* pi specific stiff */
#endif
```

I don't have a PI at hand right now, so I'm not absolutely sure if the macro `__arm__` is correct, but `gcc` and `g++` should work, see [sourceforge article on architecture defines](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/).

This is a lot easier than mocking everything, but on the other hand the code is not even compiled on your PC, so not even compiler errors would show up here.

Comment: *"the code is not even compiled on your PC"* is kind of a risky assumption ... there are cross-compilers, you know ... in fact there are whole bundles of cross-compiler **and** emulators out there, its very possible to write, compile and run code for another platform on your PC, thats what i did for a living a few years ago